# Solving integral numerically using sympy

Tags: scipy, sympy, integral

Hi I'm having a hard time solving this equation in python (34), I also added 35 and 36 as information for Ci.[image: Eq 34]

[image: Eq 35, 36]

Here is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import sympy as smp
smp.init_printing(True)
C_i = smp.Function('C_i')
t, x, v, tao = smp.symbols('t, x, v, tao', positive=True) # tao = lambda x, v: x/v
m2 = smp.Integral((C_i(t-tao))**2,(tao, 0,t))
m2.doit()
m2_s = m2.doit().simplify()
t_arr = np.arange(0,1000,1)
fm2_1 = smp.lambdify((x,v,t), m2_s, ['scipy', {'C_i': lambda e:0.666666}])
```

I'm not sure how to add the condition that tao = x/v. I do not need to use sympy its just what I could find online as a guide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72900048/solving-an-integral-with-dirac-delta-using-sympy

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72912501/problems-with-quad-when-using-lambdify

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Integral.transform` method to do a substitution in an integral:

```
In [10]: m2
Out[10]: 
t              
⌠              
⎮   2          
⎮ Cᵢ (t - τ) dτ
⌡              
0              

In [11]: m2.transform(tau, (x/v, x))
Out[11]: 
t⋅v              
 ⌠               
 ⎮    2⎛    x⎞   
 ⎮  Cᵢ ⎜t - ─⎟   
 ⎮     ⎝    v⎠   
 ⎮  ────────── dx
 ⎮      v        
 ⌡               
 0
```

Otherwise I'm not really sure what your equation 34 is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 0):

Your sympy expression is an unevaluated integral:

```
In [10]: m2_s
Out[10]:
```

[image]

The resulting lambdified function uses `scipy.integrate.quad`:

```
In [13]: help(fm2_1)
Help on function _lambdifygenerated:

_lambdifygenerated(x, v, t)
    Created with lambdify. Signature:
    
    func(x, v, t)
    
    Expression:
    
    Integral(C_i(t - tao)**2, (tao, 0, t))
    
    Source code:
    
    def _lambdifygenerated(x, v, t):
        return quad(lambda tao: C_i(t - tao)**2, 0, t)[0]
    
    
    Imported modules:
    
    from scipy.integrate import quad
```

While you specified `x,v` as function arguments, they aren't used in the expression at all!

If you want more control over the `scipy` integration, you should `lambdify` the expression that you want to integrate:

```
In [14]: fn = smp.lambdify((C_i,t,tao),(C_i(t-tao))**2)    
In [15]: help(fn)
Help on function _lambdifygenerated:

_lambdifygenerated(C_i, t, tao)
    Created with lambdify. Signature:
    
    func(C_i, t, tao)
    
    Expression:
    
    C_i(t - tao)**2
    
    Source code:
    
    def _lambdifygenerated(C_i, t, tao):
        return C_i(t - tao)**2
```